# Print output on same line from Powershell function

Tags: powershell

I have a function which returns some instances of a database:

```
function Get-ServiceStatus ([string[]]$server)
{
    foreach ($s in $computer)
    {
        if (Test-Connection $s -Count 2 -Quiet)
        {
            Get-WmiObject win32_Service -Computer $s |
            where {$_.DisplayName -match "SQL Server"} | 
            select Name
        }
    }
}

"Instans/er: "
get-servicestatus
```

It filters out the name of each instance, and prints it as such:

```
Instans/er:

Name          
----          
instance1
instance2     
instance3
```

How do I format the text to print out as:

```
Instans/er: instance1, instance2, instance3
```

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at `format-list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your current function, you could do:

```
$InstanceList = (Get-ServiceStatus).Name -Join ', '
"Instans/er: $InstanceList"
```

Or you could modify the function to output this way by default (bearing in mind this results in your function no longer returning a collection of names, but instead a single string that might be less useful):

```
function Get-ServiceStatus ([string[]]$server)
{
    $InstanceList = foreach ($s in $computer)
    {
        if (Test-Connection $s -Count 2 -Quiet)
        {
            Get-WmiObject win32_Service -Computer $s |
            where {$_.DisplayName -match "SQL Server"} | 
            select -ExpandProperty Name
        }
    }
    $InstanceList -Join ', '

}

"Instans/er: $(Get-ServiceStatus)"
```

Both solutions just use the `-Join` operator to join the collection of Name strings with  a comma and space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Get-ServiceStatus ([string[]]$server)
{
    $instances = foreach ($s in $computer)
                {
                    if (Test-Connection $s -Count 2 -Quiet)
                    {
                        Get-WmiObject win32_Service -Computer $s |
                        where {$_.DisplayName -match "SQL Server"} | 
                        select -ExpandProperty Name
                    }
                }
    foreach ($instance in $instances)
    {
        $formattedinstances = $instance + ", "
    }
    $formattedinstances = $formattedinstances.Substring(0,$formattedinstances.Length-2)
    return $formattedinstances
}
"Instans/er: $(Get-ServiceStatus)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said already, I would strongly suggest to improve your function to be an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-6) as follows:

```
function Get-SqlServerInstance {
    param (
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]$Computer = "localhost" # (default)
    )
    process {
        Get-WmiObject win32_Service -Computer $Computer | where {
            $_.DisplayName -match "SQL Server"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$instances = $servers | where {
    Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet
} | Get-SqlServerInstance  | select -Unique -ExpandProperty Name
"Instans/er: $($instances -join ', ')"
```

If that is too long for you, wrap that in a small helper function:

```
function Print_ServiceStatus ([string[]]$servers) {
    $instances = $servers | where {
        Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet
    } | Get-SqlServerInstance  | select -Unique -ExpandProperty Name
    Write-Host "Instans/er: $($instances -join ', ')"
}
```

But, I am very sure it would make sense to output the Computer name too:

```
$servers | Get-SqlServerInstance | select PSComputerName, Name
```

IMHO, this would be the best practice and most **"PowerShell-ish"** way to do it.

**Benefits:**

- `Get-SqlServerInstance` is a more appropriate name describing what the function does
- The function now returns objects, not strings (the way to go in PowerShell!)
- It works with the pipeline now (always preferred for performance)
- The `Test-Connection` is not really part of the function's purpose. Your function should throw if it cannot connect! So I moved it to outside the function.